# Django filtering queryset based on input from URL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get an API endpoint `api/v1/device-groups/?customer=<customer_uuid>` which returns the device groups related to the `customer_uuid` given in the URL but am not sure how to create this.

`models.py`

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    group_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    customer_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    device_group_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('customer_name', 'customer_uuid')


class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, source='customer_uuid')

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ('device_group_name', 'group_uuid', 'color', 'is_default', 'customer')
```

I am not sure what I should do in my `views.py` and `urls.py`

`urls.py`

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'device-groups', views.DeviceGroupViewSet, base_name='device-groups')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

My `views.py` that returns all device groups related to this `customer_uuid` upon a GET request to `/api/v1/device-groups/?customer_uuid=0bc899e9-4864-4183-8bcd-06937c572143/`

```
class DeviceGroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DeviceGroupSerializer

queryset = DeviceGroup.objects.filter(customer_uuid='0bc899e9-4864-4183-8bcd-06937c572143')
```

I tried to override `get_queryset` like this, but it results in a `KeyError`

`views.py`

```
class DeviceGroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DeviceGroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return DeviceGroup.objects.filter(customer_uuid=self.kwargs['customer_uuid'])
```

What do I need to change to get an API endpoint `/api/v1/device-groups/?customer=<customer_uuid>/` that returns filtered device groups?

### EDIT

Changing my `views.py` solved it for me.

```
class DeviceGroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DeviceGroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return DeviceGroup.objects.filter(customer_uuid=self.request.GET['customer_uuid'])
```

Comment: `?customer=<uuid>` are request query parameters that are not part of the URL path. They are part of the `request.GET` dictionary or `request.data` for drf.

Comment: Thanks alot! They are indeed part of the `request.GET` dictionary. `return DeviceGroup.objects.filter(customer_uuid=self.request.GET['customer_uuid'])` solved my problem.

Comment: I've never used query parameters with DRF but if you look at this [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) it looks like you could also get the parameter like so `customer_uuid = self.request.query_params.get('customer_uuid', None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything after the `?` in a URL is considered to be a list of query parameters: `?customer=<uuid>` means you're passing the query parameter `customer` to your request. They are not part of the actual URL path.

These query parameters are all added to the `QueryDict` `request.GET` by Django. In DRF, they can be accessed in `request.data` as well.